How would people arrange for protection in a truly propertyless society?
I’m working on a story involving a society completely devoid of property.  Communists often want to abolish private property, like owning factories and the like, while maintaining personal property, like owning your toothbrush.  Whereas what I’m envisioning is a society which has neither person property nor private property.  In this society, everyone is allowed to do whatever they want, like going on any land, using any object, etc., as long as they don’t aggress against the body of other people.  In particular, you can use any object if someone isn’t using the object right this second.  Matt Bruenig’s thought experiment of “Grab What You Can World” is instructive in this regard.
My question is, how might denizens of such a society plausibly arrange for their own protection?  I imagine people would spend a lot of time building locks and gates and so on, which without the use of violence prevents a person from places and objects you don’t want them to access.  But beyond that, is it plausible that a government could be created in this sort of society?  Or would the fact that no one owns anything mean that taxation is not a feasible funding mechanism for government?

You are asking 3 different questions here, 2 of which are highly speculative. Please narrow down to 1 answerable question.

I find a few amputees and hire them to tie their damaged limbs to the ground in shifts. Now everybody is stepping on their prosthetics. They all give everybody consent to step on them, but they give me legal authority to revoke consent for stepping on them. Now I'm allowed to use physical violence against whoever I want as long as I shout "I revoke consent! Get off that amputee's prosthetic body part!" first. I am now the dictator of the world, and shall constitute a police force and a judiciary to enforce contract law for the benefit of all.

@gs Hire them with what? You have no possessions. You'll have to find people who'll follow you for some other reason (i.e., found a cult).

@Keshav Srinivasan a world with out property is an oxymoron. People will always protect their stuff in some way or another that is just how the world operates. What you described is a society in which stealing is okay and i wonder how people would even produce goods in such circumstances.

The resource you link to doesn't seem to exist there at least not under that name, nor is the author recognized. Could you mend the link or clarify how to find what you're pointing at?

Could you also give much greater detail about how the world operates, the legal system, economics and law-enforcement as at present the context for what you're asking is so unclear as to make it impossible to identify what's even possible there.

We try to avoid closing questions of new users, but you're asking for a discussion, which is prohibited in the [tour]. VTC:Needs More Focus until you narrow the post to one and only one question. In the mean time, why would anyone in your society go to work? If they can walk into anyone's home and eat the food not being eaten at the moment, take the TV not being watched, sleep on the bed not being slept in. Why would anyone go to a factory to process the food, build the TV, etc.? Force?

The cliff dwellings in the American Southwest were built to hide corn from those who would take it. Some of those are in very difficult places to reach even with modern climbing equipment.

Protect them from what? they don't have property to steal. Don't want them to access, what right do you have o deny them access? I think you need to consider the full implication of NO property.

@cadence Exchange of favors, of course. If they don't want to be the best-paid people in the world after I'm the dictator, I'll pay them up front with a nice haircut.

VTC - Opinion based. The short answer is 'Like all Communist societies, it won't work' - The longer answer is a very detailed and in-depth breakdown of the fundamental assumptions that Marx built on (about the essential Human nature, for example) that were wrong and how property rights (and the right to own the fruits of your labour) is a logical extension of bodily rights - the person who does not own the fruits of their labour is a Slave.

Your society is an oxymoron
Let be very blunt a society like you described it can't exist. It's physically impossible for them to exist.
So your world is eiter:

A: A society in which these laws are universal. This means that every body has to abide by these rules. Problem is that there ie no one around to enforce these rules because that would require ownership of specific things. Which is impossible in your world. I mean imagine every one was allowed to take a cops gun away. This leads to people eventually acquiring power and creating scenario B.

B: Or you have some people that are allowed ownership of objects. This however means that the universal concepts of your free for all society is no no longer applicable. Also no one is can now prevent them from turning your world into their personal cleptocracy. Which is how most communist societies ended up looking like in our world.


You need an almighty being to
To make your world remotely possible you essentially need an omnipresent very powerful godly being dedicated to your idea.

This godly being will remain unchanging and cannot be overcome in anyway and it will see and know everything. Only in this way can it enforce your societies rules.

This being would essentially smite every one going against the system and would be the only form of authority in your world at least to some extent. Though i would suggest keeping their interference low to make your world not completely boring.


What would your world look like
With this establish we can broadly look at what your world would look like.

A tribal anarchy would be the most likely result. As everyone can steal anything there is literally no way to establish a supply chain for any sophisticated goods because hey you can just steal any intermediate goods.

Your society would end up in hunter gather communities with poor level of technology. Because you can only trust a small group of people to not run of with your stuff and leave you to starve.

Agricultural communities might still be hidden somewhere. But they would be far and and few in between and very well hidden because when one comes to steal their food they are going to starve

The only way to protect your goods is essentially to hide them somewhere lock them up and make it hard to get to. Depending on how much violence the godly being allows as being allowed to kill someone directly would topple your society. Your world might build deadly traps to protect their goods or make it it otherwise impossible to get to them.

Your technology would like be stone age level. This because for anything more sophisticated you need established supply chains which as i pointed out are almost impossible to establish.

There is the possibility of building up a small consensus to not rob delivers of goods and establish maybe iron or bronze age technology in some limited fashion. But anything more would really stretch it.


So that is about anything i got. Of course you could always say that your godly being intervenes in the most convenient possible or your people are just super nice and would never do bad things. I this case just forget anything i said and built whatever ever world you want. No one one is forcing you to do anything.
Note: English is not my primary language so please excuse any grammar or spelling errors.

Post-scarcity of not?
The answer will depend on whether you have a society where scarcity exists, or not. It works much better in a post-scarcity world, but IMO in both cases it results in a society where a there is something that looks very much like property.
First, world where scarcity exists. In such a world, people have a lot of incentives to keep valuable resources and objects to themselves and away from other people, but they aren't allowed to use violence to prevent others from taking those things and aren't able to get the government to use violence against these people (which is what law enforcement is). This is basically a world where property exists but theft of property is completely legal. So you're quite right that this would result in people devising other strategies to keep others away, like putting scarce resources behind locks, hiding them where no-one can find them, maybe carrying something valuable on you at all times.
To show why this looks a lot like property, let's suppose I have a whole lot of valuable things stashed in a warehouse. Anyone who can get into the warehouse can take whatever they want, but let's say that it's really hard to break into it. However, I can get ask other people to do things for me, and in exchange, I can open the warehouse with my key and give them some of that valuable stuff. So you have something like an employer-employee relationship in this supposedly property-free world.
You're right in that there would be a problem with collecting taxes in a world like this, but there is a bigger problem. Our society functions because we can trade our labour in exchange for some valuable property. So, doing useful work is a way to get your hands on some valuable property. However, in your society, the best way to get your hands on valuable goods is to be very good at stealing them or knowing where they are stashed. Except these valuable goods won't even exist, because no-one made them, because everyone is too busy trying to yoink stuff that is currently in someone else's possession.
In a post-scarcity society, this works much better. Arguments can be made that you can never have a completely post-scarcity society, but let's not get into that now. Let's just say that mundane things like food, clothes, cars etc are all made by robots or something and there is more than enough for everyone.
You can still take someone else's car if you want to, but there is no real reason to do so, because you can just get a new one from the automated factory. In this case, you'll still get a free car that you like, and then keep using it, because you like that type of car, and you like the way it handles and you're familiar with how it works. So in a sense, this is 'your' car. Anyone can take it at any time, but they have no reason to because they're all driving 'their' cars that they like more than yours. Which to me still looks a lot like property.
Post-scarcity propertyless world has a better chance of existing because it avoids some of the problems that a world with scarcity has. You don't need people doing mundane jobs, because that is all done by robots. People can still do other jobs because of wanting to do something useful for society, or to do something interesting to occupy their time, or maybe for status reasons, to impress the ladies (or men). A government can function because people will work in government on a voluntary basis. But like I said, it seems like such a society basically still has property by another name.

Such a "post-scarcity" world is still highly dependent on energy which might be scarce. It is dependent on those scarce few who know how to keep the robots working.

Such a society has been described in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Dispossessed - and  developed a internal caste system of informal committees and roles who controlled access to society wide resource distribution. And society put pressure on members allowing certain things or not. Taboos. Laws. Call them what you want.
Also peace, as we know it only upholds in times of plenty. As soon as there is bad times ahead, calls for stricter morals get louder, restarting the upholding of laws/property through some enslaved third-sex contract-cult or law institutions. Warlords, companies or family structures(clans) reappear and distribute scarce resources among themselves.
Its just not in anything in nature, to not fill any niche exponentially and then bark at the resulting scarcer territory. Its like physics, you can dream of a world were water falls upwards, but it never does. Even we, eating for a century now fossilized sun with the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haber_process are reaching the limits again and finding out how ugly our species can be under stress.
